# What is wrong with the attempts at defining a Recursive Function

Tags: recursion

What is wrong with these attempts at defining a recursive function?

(i) $f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1, f(2) = 1, f(3) = 3, f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)$ $\quad$$for \ n \ge 2$

(ii) $f(0) = 0, f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)$ $\quad$$for \ n \ge 2$

Comment: For **(i)** look more closely at what happens for $n=2\,$. For **(ii)** at $n=1$.

Comment: In the first one, $f(1)+f(2)\ne f(3)$, breaking the function rule. In the second, the first term must also be given, because in order to find the next term, two terms before it must be known.

Answer (score 1):

**i**

$f(n) \neq f(n-1) + f(n-2)$ for $n \geq 2$ because $f(3) = 3$ and $f(2) + f(1) = 2$

**ii**

$f(1)$ is not defined, which is needed to define $f(2)$, which is need to define $f(3)$, ... etc.

Comment: for ii. if it was for n greater or equal to 1. would it still be wrong? why?

Comment: The recursion defines a term using the two terms before it. So you need two terms to generate the sequence of terms. For your specific question, how would you find the value of $f(1)$

Answer (score 1):

For $i) $,  $f (3) $ must be $=2$

For $ii) $, you need $f (1) $ to compute $f (2 ) $.